# How Do I scroll to a string in a Rich Text Box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I ahve a RTB with sufficent text that scrolling is needed
user enters a string and I highlight all occurrences using  a combination of Find and Select which is great but now I want the ability for a user to press Next and the next higlighted instance should be visible say 2at /3rd of the bounding rectangle ( I would even settle for at the top of the bound.

How do I scroll to an index basically ( I am caching the indices as I find and markup )

oh also this is C# Winforms .NET 2.0

Comment: What language and platform is this question regards to? Winforms? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the selection start to the next location, and then use ScrollToCaret to scroll to that location in the rich text box.

```
rText1.SelectionStart = i
rText1.ScrollToCaret()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void myrichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myrichTextBox.SelectionStart = myrichTextBox.Text.Length; //Set the current caret position             at the end
   myrichTextBox.ScrollToCaret(); //Now scroll it automatically
}
```